# Apple M2 - Number of Hex Digits in Memory Address

Tags: c++

I am using Xcode on Apple M2. I have a simple C++ program that prints address of `int x` like this:

`cout << "Address of x is: " << &x;`

The output has 9 hex digits: `0x16fdff260`

Shouldn't the address have 8 hex digits (32 bits) ? Why 9 digits?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The M2 is a 64-bit processor.  Addresses can be up to 64 bits, or 16 hex digits.

Comment: You wouldn't write the leading 0s in front of a 1, why would you write them in front of hex?

Comment: Yea, but shouldn't the hex digits be even in number?

Comment: No.  Why?  If you had the number 0x135, you would print it as 0x135.

Comment: Consider the hex value 0x0a, you don't have to write the 0 for the upper nibble, 0xa is adequate to fully represent the value

Comment: If you want to print the leading 0s see here:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416425/printing-zero-padded-hex-with-stdcout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416425/printing-zero-padded-hex-with-stdcout) and here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760252/how-can-i-print-0x0a-instead-of-0xa-using-cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760252/how-can-i-print-0x0a-instead-of-0xa-using-cout)

Comment: Remarkable: only one correct comment. The question isn’t about leading zeros.

Comment: `cout << "Address has " << (sizeof(&x) * 2) << " hex digits, or " << (sizeof(&x) * 8) << " bits\n";`

Comment: @TimRoberts's is the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

Each pair of hex digits represents a byte. As the M2 is a 64-bit processor, addresses are 64 bits or 8 bytes. This means an address *may* have 16 digits, but leading zeroes are not printed.

You can use the `<iomanip>` header to format your output with the leading zeroes.