# C++ stream manipulator to add tabs to every line

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm would like to modify a stream so that every time something is output to the stream each line is prepended with some number of tabs. It seems that a manipulator is the way to go about this but none of the examples I've found make it clear how to manipulate in this way.

Is this a reasonable thing for a manipulator and if so how?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/q/30073287/3233393. Not a duplicate, but may be solved with the same pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not reasonable. That would require you to detect whenever the stream output a new line, and then follow it up with a tab. In order to do that, you'd have to, at the very least, rewrite the `put` and `write` member functions of `std::basic_ostream` in such a way that they check for your manipulator's injected state, and act accordingly whenever they see a `\n` in the output. Definitely not reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, this explains why I'm having trouble finding references for something like it.