# iostream maniputor via xalloc/iword or via derived class?

Tags: c++, stream, manipulators

I need to implement a C++ iostream manipulator. Reading here and there it seems that people uses 2 ways

1. using `ios_base::xalloc` and `ios_base::iword`
2. implementing a derived class from iostream like example below.

I like the second way but probably it has cons that I cannot see or understand compared to the first way.

```
    // Example of point 2
    struct mystream : public iostream
    {  
      ostream& o_;
      mystream(ostream& o) : o_(o) {} 

      ostream& operator << (int a) {
        // do something with o and a
        o << "<A>" << a << "</A>";
        return *this;
      }     
     };

     ostream mymanipulator(ostream& out) { 
       return mystream(out);
     }
```

I found a very good implementation of way #2 in this post [Custom manipulator for C++ iostream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535444/custom-manipulator-for-c-iostream/535647#535647).

It looks to me that `xalloc and iword` are more used to store some custom internal state for my custom stream to be used at some point.

Comment: What's the actual use case you're trying to implement?  I have used xalloc() to great effect before but it's not for every use case.

Comment: Nothing to answer - if you have an internal state to save (1) - otherwise (2)

Comment: @John it is a manipulator for HTML object..Anyway I think about these 2 topics like Dieter  is going: saving a state vs. something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend either of those things.

> Using `ios_base::xalloc` and `ios_base::iword`

You haven't exactly told us how you would use the data stored in the stream, but it's a bit unintuitive to set `iword()` each and every time you want to write.

> Implementing a derived class from `iostream`...

Normally you don't want to inherit from the stream base classes. The only case in which it might be useful is when you're wrapping a custom stream around a stream buffer, but that's usually for convenience.

Another problem is that your inserter returns `std::ostream`, meaning that when chaining operators you'll only be writing to the `std::ostream` base object on the second write:

```
mystream str;
str << 100  // writes "<A>100</A>"
    << 200; // only writes 200
```

---

The idiomatic solution is to customize a `std::num_put<char>` facet for your stream's locale. This way you wrap the functionality directly under the hood of the stream so that it doesn't change the way the user uses the stream.

Comment: ok. For the ostream returned by value you are right; it doesn't make sense..I found this code that does better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535444/custom-manipulator-for-c-iostream/535647#535647. For the num_put I am reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335193/sticky-custom-stream-manipulatoryet ..looks intreaguing...

Comment: This document is from 2001 but is useful to tell you about facets:

http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-defining-a-facet/184403785#4

Comment: I'd like an explanation of why " it's a bit unintuitive to set iword() each and every time you want to write."  iword() and pword() (properly encapsulated) seem much superior to a facet, which has to be imbued into the locale and the stream each time it changes.

Comment: @Spencer I'm not sure why I said that. Of course setting `iword` and `pword` is much more efficient than imbuing and unimbuing a locale whenever we want different functionality.